# Convert Array of objects to array of arrays and values

Tags: javascript

I want to convert this:

```
data= [{id: 1, name: 'james', country: 'US'}, {id: 2, name: 'john', country: 'NG'}]
```

to this:

```
newdata =[[1,'james', 'US'], [2,'john', 'NG']]
```

I tried pushing the data to a new array but couldn't give me my desired result:

```
const newdata = [];

for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  newdata.push(data[index].name);
}
```

but it's giving me just the names. I understand that this line `data[index].name` is the cause.

Comment: `data.map(Object.values)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function:
`function transformData(data) { return data.map(item => [item.id, item.name, item.country]); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.values to turn an object to an array with only their values:

```js
data = [{id: 1, name: 'james', country: 'US'}, {id: 2, name: 'john', country: 'NG'}]

convertedData = data.map(d => Object.values(d))
console.log(convertedData)
```